# Sum all possible combinations in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df containing several columns, but two of them look like:

```
number output colour
1         1    green
2         1    red
3         1    orange
4         0    green
5         1    green
```

I need to find all possible combinations and the number of occurences there so I expect something like

```
1green    2
1red      1
1orange   1
0green    1
```

Using this [python: Combination of two Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285893/python-combination-of-two-columns) I found all possible combinations, but I do not know how to do the sum. Or is there any solution to do it in one step?

THank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with joined columns:

```
s = (df.output.astype(str) + df.colour).value_counts()
print (s)
1green     2
1red       1
0green     1
1orange    1
dtype: int64
```

Or is possible use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
s = df.groupby(['output','colour']).size()
print (s)
output  colour
0       green     1
1       green     2
        orange    1
        red       1
dtype: int64
```

Or [`DateFrame.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DateFrame.value_counts.html)

```
s = df[['output','colour']].value_counts()
print (s)
output  colour
1       green     2
0       green     1
1       orange    1
        red       1
dtype: int64
```

Last for DataFrame use:

```
s = s.reset_index(name='count')
```

EDIT:

For all combinations use:

```
s = df.groupby(['output','colour']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
print (s)
output  colour
0       green     1
        orange    0
        red       0
1       green     2
        orange    1
        red       1
dtype: int64

s = df[['output','colour']].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
print (s)
output  colour
0       green     1
        orange    0
        red       0
1       green     2
        orange    1
        red       1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Wow!  `df[['output','colour']].value_counts()`  That's new.  When did they add that functionality?

Comment: @piRSquared - yes, exactly.

Comment: @piRSquared I think v1.1+ I discovered this just yesterday too :)

Comment: thank you, that are so elegant solutions!

Comment: @ZuzanaTelefony - You are welcome! Btw, it seems your nick is like in czech or slovak language, `Telefony` means `phones` ;)

Comment: @jezrael, you are right :) I am from Slovakia.

Comment: @ZuzanaTelefony - tak to sa tesim, vitaj ;)

Comment: @jezrael, dakujem. Teba by som na nase konciny netipla :)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
pd.value_counts([*zip(df.output, df.colour)])

(1, green)     2
(0, green)     1
(1, orange)    1
(1, red)       1
dtype: int64
```